# Purpose of for:index in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

If I execute below code then `{index}`    starts from 0 but I want use this as a sequence number whcih should start from 1.

```
<template for:each={array} for:item="product" for:index="index">
              <tr key={ar.apexId}>
                   <td style="z-index: 4;">
                      {index}
                   </td>
              </tr>
       </template>
```

now I cannot do this `{index+1}`, other than adding a key value pair to the array for sequence number is there any other way to use for:index to show seq number which will start with 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can start from another value. So, for accomplishing that, maybe, create a custom accessor that inserts some dummy data at the first element

```js
    @track array;

    get _array() {
        return [undefined, ...this.array];
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.array = [
            1,2,3,4
        ];
    }
```

And in your template, ignore all the elements that don't evaluate to true.

```html
    <template for:each={_array} for:item="ar" for:index="index">
        <tr if:true={ar} key={ar}>
            <td style="z-index: 4;">
                {index}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

In this example, if one of the values of the array was 0 it would also be overridden, so all the elements you want to render should evaluate to true when casting them to boolean. But if the array is an array of objects, passing the undefined would just do the trick.